# Vega-Lite Stacked Bar chart show values as percentage of monthly total

Tags: vega-lite, deneb

I need to show count values as percentage of monthly total. Here's the screenshot.
Please help me.

I've tried Transform but not very helpful.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ29O.png)

I've looked everywhere and googles as much as i can but not help...

Answer (score 0):

You have complete control of the value and format you want for each "text" mark in Deneb\Vega-Lite; I can't imagine that an appropriate "transform" is not available. Please upload a sample PBIX with data that illustrates your issue and a screenshot of the Deneb visual in question marked-up with what you'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example you can test with:

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/barley.json"},
  "title": {
    "text": ["Stacked Bar chart", "Showing % values over total value stacks"],
    "frame": "group"
  },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"color": "independent"}},
  "width": 500,
  "height": 250,
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "yield"},
        "y": {"field": "variety", "stack": "zero"},
        "color": {"field": "site"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "joinaggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "yield", "as": "total"}],
          "groupby": ["variety"]
        },
        {"calculate": "datum.yield / datum.total", "as": "percentage"}
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "text", "dx": -15, "dy": 0},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "yield", "stack": "zero"},
        "y": {"field": "variety"},
        "color": {
          "field": "site",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {"range": ["white"]},
          "legend": null
        },
        "text": {
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "field": "percentage",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "format": ".0%"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```